# Javascript - Parse one JSON error and error array in the same variable?

Tags: javascript, json

I'm getting from my server a JSON with a list of errors. When there is more than one I receive the following:

```
{
    "ErrorFuncional": [
        {
            "CodigoError": "1020",
            "MotivoError": "xxxx",
            "PosicionError": "xxxx",
            "ValorOriginal": "33333"
        },
        {
            "CodigoError": "103",
            "MotivoError": "xxxx",
            "PosicionError": "xxxx",
            "ValorOriginal": "111"
        },
        {
            "CodigoError": "110901",
            "MotivoError": "xxxx",
            "PosicionError": "xxxx",
            "ValorOriginal": "222"
        }
    ]
}
```

But when there is only one error I get this:

```
{
    "ErrorFuncional":
        {
            "CodigoError": "1020",
            "MotivoError": "xxxx",
            "PosicionError": "xxxx",
            "ValorOriginal": "33333"
        }
}
```

I declared the errors variable as an array of errors so when I try to parse **one** error I get an exception.

> Is it possible to convert the error into an array of one element before parsing it to JSON? Otherwise how can I handle this situation?

Thanks!

Comment: If possible, the server should be changed to *always* return an array. Having inconsistent return types is… bad.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```js
let ErrorFuncional = {
  "CodigoError": "1020",
  "MotivoError": "xxxx",
  "PosicionError": "xxxx",
  "ValorOriginal": "33333"
};
    
function convertToArray(array)  {
  if (Array.isArray(array) === false) {
   return {ErrorFuncional: [array]};
 } else {
    return {ErrorFuncional: array};
  }
}
    
console.log(convertToArray(ErrorFuncional))
```